# Camunda ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda

Error start happens last five days, never was before, camunda spring-boot-starter  version is 3.5.5.

```
ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error preparing statement.  Cause: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
### The error may exist in org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/mapping/entity/Job.xml
### The error may involve org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobEntity.selectNextJobsToExecute
### The error occurred while executing a query
### SQL: SELECT SUB.* FROM (     select       RES.* , row_number() over (ORDER BY RES.ID_ asc) rnk FROM ( select distinct RES.*      from ACT_RU_JOB RES      where (RES.RETRIES_ > 0)       and (               RES.DUEDATE_ is null or                   RES.DUEDATE_ <= ?       )    and (RES.LOCK_OWNER_ is null or RES.LOCK_EXP_TIME_ < ?)       and RES.SUSPENSION_STATE_ = 1                 and (      (      RES.EXCLUSIVE_ = 1           and not exists(             select J2.* from ACT_RU_JOB J2             where J2.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ = RES.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_                                           -- from the same proc. inst.             and (J2.EXCLUSIVE_ = 1)         
-- also exclusive             and (J2.LOCK_OWNER_ is not null and J2.LOCK_EXP_TIME_ >= ?)  -- in progress             )    )     or      RES.EXCLUSIVE_ = 0        )            )RES ) SUB WHERE SUB.rnk >= ? AND SUB.rnk < ? ORDER BY SUB.rnk
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error preparing statement.  Cause: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection.
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Did you see the "Unable to acquire JDBC Connection" part? Check that your database is accepting connections and you have the right credentials. Also check that `Job.xml` mentioned.

Comment: Database hase proper credentials definitely, there were no changes there from 2019. And this issue start happens on Oct 06

Comment: database is H2  - i dont see any reason whe server can not connect to it because its server-local.

Answer (score 0):

You Spring boot starter version indicates that you are on a quite dated Camunda release. Upgrade, also for the relevant security fixes.

Is the there more error long than the snippet you shared? *"Unable to acquire JDBC Connection."* could mean that you connection pool ran out of connections. You are  indicating that it worked fine before. Has the usage of the system increased recently? Then you may need to increase the connection pool size.

(I would not recommend to use the embedded h2 database for any production like scenario. Get e.e.g a PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full exception message:

```
ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context:
```

#### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error preparing statement.  Cause: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

#### The error may exist in org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/mapping/entity/Job.xml

#### The error may involve org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobEntity.selectNextJobsToExecute

#### The error occurred while executing a query

#### SQL: SELECT SUB.* FROM (     select       RES.* , row_number() over (ORDER BY RES.ID_ asc) rnk FROM ( select distinct RES.*      from ACT_RU_JOB RES      where (RES.RETRIES_ > 0)       and (                   RES.DUEDATE_ is null or                   RES.DUEDATE_ <= ?       )       and (RES.LOCK_OWNER_ is null or RES.LOCK_EXP_TIME_ < ?)       and RES.SUSPENSION_STATE_ = 1                 and (      (      RES.EXCLUSIVE_ = 1           and not exists(             select J2.* from ACT_RU_JOB J2             where J2.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ = RES.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_                                           -- from the same proc. inst.             and (J2.EXCLUSIVE_ = 1)                                                              -- also exclusive             and (J2.LOCK_OWNER_ is not null and J2.LOCK_EXP_TIME_ >= ?)  -- in progress             )    )     or           RES.EXCLUSIVE_ = 0        )            )RES ) SUB WHERE SUB.rnk >= ? AND SUB.rnk < ? ORDER BY SUB.rnk

#### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error preparing statement.  Cause: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: Hikari - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:695)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:197)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:104)
... 41 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:107)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:134)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:470)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor458.invoke(Unknown Source)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:266)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle.doGetConnection(HibernateJpaDialect.java:430)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle.getConnection(HibernateJpaDialect.java:419)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder.getConnection(ConnectionHolder.java:162)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:226)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy210.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.instantiateStatement(PreparedStatementHandler.java:87)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.BaseStatementHandler.prepare(BaseStatementHandler.java:88)
... 26 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error preparing statement.  Cause: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.BaseStatementHandler.prepare(BaseStatementHandler.java:97)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.prepare(RoutingStatementHandler.java:59)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doQuery(BatchExecutor.java:91)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:324)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:83)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:148)
... 19 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:

#### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error preparing statement.  Cause: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

#### The error may exist in org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/mapping/entity/Job.xml

#### The error may involve org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobEntity.selectNextJobsToExecute

#### The error occurred while executing a query

#### SQL: SELECT SUB.* FROM (     select       RES.* , row_number() over (ORDER BY RES.ID_ asc) rnk FROM ( select distinct RES.*      from ACT_RU_JOB RES      where (RES.RETRIES_ > 0)       and (                   RES.DUEDATE_ is null or                   RES.DUEDATE_ <= ?       )       and (RES.LOCK_OWNER_ is null or RES.LOCK_EXP_TIME_ < ?)       and RES.SUSPENSION_STATE_ = 1                 and (      (      RES.EXCLUSIVE_ = 1           and not exists(             select J2.* from ACT_RU_JOB J2             where J2.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_ = RES.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_                                           -- from the same proc. inst.             and (J2.EXCLUSIVE_ = 1)                                                              -- also exclusive             and (J2.LOCK_OWNER_ is not null and J2.LOCK_EXP_TIME_ >= ?)  -- in progress             )    )     or           RES.EXCLUSIVE_ = 0        )            )RES ) SUB WHERE SUB.rnk >= ? AND SUB.rnk < ? ORDER BY SUB.rnk

#### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error preparing statement.  Cause: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

```
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:150)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSession.selectList(DbSqlSession.java:97)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.selectListWithRawParameter(DbEntityManager.java:184)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.selectList(DbEntityManager.java:176)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.selectList(DbEntityManager.java:172)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.selectList(DbEntityManager.java:161)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobManager.findNextJobsToExecute(JobManager.java:197)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.AcquireJobsCmd.execute(AcquireJobsCmd.java:60)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.AcquireJobsCmd.execute(AcquireJobsCmd.java:38)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:28)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:107)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:46)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:70)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:33)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.SequentialJobAcquisitionRunnable.acquireJobs(SequentialJobAcquisitionRunnable.java:158)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.SequentialJobAcquisitionRunnable.run(SequentialJobAcquisitionRunnable.java:76)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Еhe workload has not increased to any great extent recently. And we dont have any database settings for camunda in spring properties.